# How can I check if input.value is the same as a random number

Tags: javascript, math

I want to make a little game where the browser selects a random number between 1 and 10 and the user has to guess which number it is. So I made an input, button and the random function, but every time, also when the inputNumber and the randomNumber are the same, it doesn't output the code I want!

```
<input type="numebr" id="userInput" />
<button id="button">Sure?</button>
<p id="awnser"></p>

let button = document.getElementById('button');
let input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
let awnser = document.getElementById('awnser');

  button.onclick = function randomFunc() {
    var randomnr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 +1);

    if (input == randomnr) {
        awnser.innerHTML = randomnr + '<br> You got it!';
    } else {
        awnser.innerHTML = randomnr + '<br> Nevermind... idiot :P';
    }
  }
```

I tried to solve it's with **parseInt**

let input = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput').value);

but it doesn't work. I think its a problem with the input value so that this is not a number rather a string...

Some tips for me?

Comment: does it generate any error?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of what you do with this line:

```
let input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
```

This gets the value when the page loads. when you click on a button, its value is the same as it was when the page got loaded. just move this line into `button.onclick` function and you should be fine.

Comment: make sure to accept it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
let input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
```

inside the onclick function

Answer (score 0):

When you have written this variable
`let input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;`
outside onclick event then it is taking the initial value when the page is loaded which is equal to empty string, if you write it like this:

```
let input = document.getElementById('userInput');
  button.onclick = function randomFunc() {
 let inputValue = input.value;
var randomnr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 +1);
```

by getting input value in the button click event, when you will enter the value in input and click on button then the value entered will be taken each time button will be clicked this is the benefit of using events.